# Is there such a field as discrete Boolean algebra?

Tags: calculus

Not just studying variables with binary states, but "infinary" ones, ie, on, off, and every value in between?

Some simple and intuitive elementary operations could include, modular addition, average, difference, bigger, smaller, and their inverses, some of which would replicate the behaviour of *and*, *or*, and *not* operations at 1 and 0 endpoints, others with no correlate.

Truth tables would now be representable as continuous planes, and there would now be a theoretically infinite number of possible boolean operations.

Comment: Fuzzy logic maybe?